# I want callback on your method "startsWithIgnoreCase"

Tags: angularjs, dexie

I have developed a demo project and configured indexed db with "dexie.js". Problem is when I try to call function `startsWithIgnoreCase` with callback.

In AngualrJS service:-

```
$rootScope.startsWithIgnoreCase = function (enteredItem) {

    return db.itemMaster.where('itemCode').startsWithIgnoreCase(enteredItem).toArray($rootScope.callfunc);
}

//Callback method is this
$rootScope.callfunc=function(items) {

    //$rootScope.collectItem angular array variable
    $rootScope.collectItem = items;
    //console.log("My close friends: " + JSON.stringify(items));
}
```

In Controller,

```
var data = $rootScope.startsWithIgnoreCase(searchText);
```

`data` always get null then I call `$rootScope.collectItem` this is first time null and then always displaying previous search item. Below is details.

Callback is not working, because I have upto 100 records in indexed db, when I call first time `startsWithIgnoreCase` method then `$rootScope.collectItem` is set to null, but again I'm trying to call same method then `$rootScope.collectItem` displaying previous searched matched value on second time. Like:

1. In my autocomplete search box when I entered item no "441" and call method `startsWithIgnoreCase` first time then `$rootScope.collectItem` set null.
2. When I'm trying to search another items no "885", then `$rootScope.collectItem` displaying previous filtered records of "441".

**Note**: I want to implement callback of `startsWithIgnoreCase` but I'm not able to find any solution.

If anybody can have any sample code of "dexie.js" with angularjs then please send me that link.

Comment: Are you sure that `db.itemMaster.where('itemCode')` is not a promise and hence your call back function should be written there, no?

Comment: Hi aruna,

i don't idea about how ti setup promise for callback.

Comment: mu code is:-
    $rootScope.startsWithIgnoreCase = function (enteredItem) {
        console.log("db.friends.where('name').startsWithIgnoreCase('da')", "heading");
        var data = [];
        dbs.PLU_MASTER.where('SkuCode').startsWithIgnoreCase(enteredItem.toString())
                         .each(function (plumaster) {
                             data.push(plumaster);
                         });
        return data;
    }